# Add application arguments to run .NET console app in Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker

In my docker file, I have this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

and I need to pass an application argument to the app, let's say `--argument`, so that the app can run inside the container.

So, I know I can run the app locally by doing

```
dotnet run -- --argument
```

but I'm stuck at trying to add the `--argument` to the Dockerfile (or anywhere, I don't know).

I tried adding `CMD ["--argument"]`, `CMD ["--", "--argument"]`in the Dockerfile, but with no success.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Are you sure this one doesn't work? ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll", "argument"]  ??

Comment: @KostyaK nope, it doesn't

Comment: Have you tried CMD["dotnet", "app.dll", "argument"] instead of ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work, by adding the argument in the Dockerfile like so:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll", "--argument"]
...
```

But I think that this is not an "absolute" solution, i.e., for instance, the argument I needed to add was not for dotnet, but for the app itself; that's why it worked through the command line with the `--` switch. Maybe the solutions proposed in the comment section won't work in all scenarios because of this detail.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party, but recent Microsoft documentation points out how to pass arguments to .NET console app:

```
docker run -it --rm counter-image 3
```

**3** is the argument. So if you need to pass `args` array, you just do it after the image name that you want to run.

I think you might already know this, but I think whoever comes to this question should also have some relevant information.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows